# Django doesn't change html when changing route

Tags: django

I created several html's for each project functionality, but when I change route, html doesn't change. The only html that appears is the homepage, index.html.

urls.py:

```
from website.views import IndexTemplateView, FuncionarioListView, FuncionarioUpdateView, FuncionarioCreateView, FuncionarioDeleteView
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

app_name = 'website'

urlpatterns = [
# GET /
url('', IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="index"),

# GET /funcionario/cadastrar
url('funcionario/cadastrar', FuncionarioCreateView.as_view(), name="cadastra_funcionario"),

# GET /funcionarios
url('funcionarios/', FuncionarioListView.as_view(), name="lista_funcionarios"),

# GET/POST /funcionario/{pk}
url('funcionario/<pk>', FuncionarioUpdateView.as_view(), name="atualiza_funcionario"),

# GET/POST /funcionarios/excluir/{pk}
url('funcionario/excluir/<pk>', FuncionarioDeleteView.as_view(), name="deleta_funcionario"),
]
```

views.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, UpdateView, CreateView, DeleteView
from helloworld.models import Funcionario
from website.forms import InsereFuncionarioForm


# PÁGINA PRINCIPAL
# ----------------------------------------------

class IndexTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "website/index.html"


# LISTA DE FUNCIONÁRIOS
# ----------------------------------------------

class FuncionarioListView(ListView):
    template_name = "website/lista.html"
    model = Funcionario
    context_object_name = "funcionarios"


# CADASTRAMENTO DE FUNCIONÁRIOS
# ----------------------------------------------

class FuncionarioCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = "website/cria.html"
    model = Funcionario
    form_class = InsereFuncionarioForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("website:lista_funcionarios")


# ATUALIZAÇÃO DE FUNCIONÁRIOS
# ----------------------------------------------

class FuncionarioUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = "website/atualiza.html"
    model = Funcionario
    fields = '__all__'
    context_object_name = 'funcionario'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("website:lista_funcionarios")


# EXCLUSÃO DE FUNCIONÁRIOS
# ----------------------------------------------

class FuncionarioDeleteView(DeleteView):
    template_name = "website/exclui.html"
    model = Funcionario
    context_object_name = 'funcionario'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("website:lista_funcionarios")
```

and an example of one of the htmls:

```html
{% extends "website/_layouts/base.html" %}

{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block title %}Cadastro de Funcionários{% endblock %}

{% block conteudo %}
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Cadastro de Funcionário</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Complete o formulário abaixo para cadastrar
            um novo <code>Funcionário</code>.
          </p>
          <form method="post">
            <!-- Não se esqueça dessa tag -->
            {% csrf_token %}

            <!-- Nome -->
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">Nome</span>
              </div>
              {% render_field form.nome class+="form-control" %}
            </div>

            <!-- Sobrenome -->
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">Sobrenome</span>
              </div>
              {% render_field form.sobrenome class+="form-control" %}
            </div>

            <!-- CPF -->
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">CPF</span>
              </div>
              {% render_field form.cpf class+="form-control" %}
            </div>

            <!-- Tempo de Serviço -->
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">Tempo de Serviço</span>
              </div>
              {% render_field form.tempo_de_servico class+="form-control" %}
            </div>

            <!-- Remuneração -->
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">Remuneração</span>
              </div>
              {% render_field form.remuneracao class+="form-control" %}
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="text-right">
              <a href="{% url 'website:lista_funcionarios' %}" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Voltar</a>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When changing route, for example to employee / register, html does not change, thank you if someone helps!

Comment: I typically see url lines written like this `url(r'^polls/'...`

Answer (score 0):

You're confused between URL syntaxes. You should be using `path` throughout.

```
path('', IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="index"),
path('funcionario/cadastrar', FuncionarioCreateView.as_view(), name="cadastra_funcionario"),

path('funcionarios/', FuncionarioListView.as_view(), name="lista_funcionarios"),

path('funcionario/<pk>', FuncionarioUpdateView.as_view(), name="atualiza_funcionario"),

path('funcionario/excluir/<pk>', FuncionarioDeleteView.as_view(), name="deleta_funcionario"),
```

With `url`, all your patterns are being interpreted as regexes, so every path will match against the first pattern which is empty.

**Edit** If you can't use path, then you need to make sure your patterns are regexes: they need to be anchored and terminated, and you must use the proper syntax to capture parameters.

```
url('^$', IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="index"),
url('^funcionario/cadastrar$', FuncionarioCreateView.as_view(), name="cadastra_funcionario"),

url('^funcionarios/$', FuncionarioListView.as_view(), name="lista_funcionarios"),

url('^funcionario/(?P<pk>.*)$', FuncionarioUpdateView.as_view(), name="atualiza_funcionario"),

url('^funcionario/excluir/(?P<pk>.*)$', FuncionarioDeleteView.as_view(), name="deleta_funcionario"),
```

Comment: I'm having problems with path, I can't import it, and my Django doesn't update, only goes to version 1.11.

Comment: F.Y.I, Path was added in version 2, so you won't see it in 1.11.See the correct way to specify a regex url in Daniel's edit.

Comment: from `django.urls import path` or from `django.conf.urls import url`

Answer (score 0):

probably the problem is in your `urls.py`.
here's some basic about regular expression (regex).

in regex, theres special characters:

`^` (caret): matches the start of the string

```
'x'    # Matches 'x' in 'x'
'xyz'  # Matches 'x' in 'xyz'
'abc'  # Not match because 'x' was not at the beginning
```

`$` (dollar sign): matches the end of the string.

```
'y'     # Matches 'y' in 'y'
'xy'    # Matches 'y' in 'xy'
'xyz'   # Not match because 'y' was not at the end
```

`r'` or `R'` : prefix for [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) (escape sequences are ignored) which is useful for regex, so it would be better to use this. from its docs:

> When an `r'` or `R'` prefix is present, backslashes are still used to quote the following character, but all backslashes are left in the string. For example, the string literal r"\n" consists of two characters: a backslash and a lowercase `n'.

which is means the r'\n' is equivalent of the '\n'.

ok. it's enough for the basic of regex.

so for your **urls.py** on this line
`url('', IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="index")`
the pattern `''` or `r''` means:
Django will look for an **empty string anywhere in the URL, which is true for every URL.**
so all of your urls will go to index page.

so, you have to use this instead:
`url(r'^$', IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="index"),`
Using both `^` and `$` together as `^$` will match an empty line/string.
it will go to the index page if and only if Django encounters an empty string,

meanwhile for your other urls, you have to use `$` at the end of each urls.

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="index"),

   url(r'funcionario/cadastrar/$', FuncionarioCreateView.as_view(), name="cadastra_funcionario"),

   url(r'funcionarios/$', FuncionarioListView.as_view(), name="lista_funcionarios"),

   url(r'funcionario/<pk>/$', FuncionarioUpdateView.as_view(), name="atualiza_funcionario"),

   url(r'funcionario/excluir/<pk>/$', FuncionarioDeleteView.as_view(), name="deleta_funcionario"),
]
```

why need to use `$` at the end?
for example, regex `r'^hello/'` 
without `$`  at the end it will match any url starting with hello like:

- hello/world
- hello/bro/
- hello/123/there/